# How can we use external style sheets in angular projects?

Tags: angular, stylesheet

How to include the external style sheets in angular projects and use them in different components.
Can anyone tell me the whole procedure of including the style sheet.

I am trying to use the custom built template in my angular project. I have all the code(HTML ,css) but i can't add or import all of the code in my angular project specially css.

Comment: add styles to index.htm using <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">

Comment: check this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components

Answer (score 1):

You can over write the styles.css file in the projectname/src/ directory.

Or you can add the styles file in question (somename.css) to the angular.json file in the styles array

```
"version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "somthing": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in **assets** folder add a folder named **css** and put all your css file inside it.
after that in the `styles.css` file (that file exist inside src folder) add imports to your css files:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import "assets/css/name_of_file.css";
```